# How to hide property of relational/nested object in swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger-ui, springfox

Is there anyone out there that knows how to hide a certain property of relational/nested object in swagger-ui (springfox)?

Lets say that I have this two classes:

**Patient Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Patient")
public class Patient extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "personalNumber", unique = true)
    private String personalNumber;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    private String startDate = new DateTime().toDateTimeISO().toString();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "clinicId")
    private Clinic clinic;
```

**Clinic Entity**

```
@Table(name = "Clinic")
public class Clinic extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    @Column(name = "clinicNumber", unique = true)
    private String clinicNumber = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)
    @Column(name = "created")
    private String created = new DateTime().toDateTimeISO().toString();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "clinic", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Set<Patient> patients = new HashSet<>();
```

If I look on swagger POST clinic the model looks like this (which is awesome):

[image: clinic model]

But when I look at POST patient, the model looks like this:

[image: patient model]

Alright, so basically my question is, is it possible to hide the "name" property of clinic in the POST patient model? But on the POST clinic model I want to show the name property.

What i'm looking for is someway to traverse down into the clinic object in the patient entity and ignore certain properties.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should in general not expose your database entities in the rest api. You have separate entities for the rest api, and separate for the database.

Comment: Whether or not to use Dto model is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Im aware of that I should not expose PK but this case is just for learning purpose. I mean, do I need to end up with one DTO for POST Clinic and one for POST Patient?

Comment: I have the same question - and I think it is really unnecessary write mapping from ObjectRequest or to Object o like o.setName(o.getName());
I have no idea why Laravel can do it - expose database object like this.